# How to send data when using Oracle Change notification from Data Access layer to Application layer

Tags: c#, oracle, notifications, data-access-layer, change-notification

Hi I am planning to use oracle change notification feature in C# using OracleDependency class. Whenever there is change in the data, we get the notifications from database that there is a change in the data access layer. So we can connect to DB and get the new data, but how can we send this new data back to the application(console app)?

Comment: do you happen to know how that notification is implemented in the rdbms? Is it by way of a trigger? If it is a row-level trigger this will certainly slow down the application. If it is an event trigger, it might miss events when under heavy load. Do you need a notification for every change or just a notification for 'there are changes available'? What Oracle rdbms version are you using?

Comment: @ik_zelf I am using oracle 10g. I need a notification that changes are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am passing a delegate function as a parameter to data access and whenver database sends notification, the event is passed to the delegate function.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [OCI Result caching](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3767781/Oracle-Database-11g-PLSQL-and-OCI-Result-Set-Caching.htm), but not sure how that fits in with C#.